# adding multiple csv files in plotly template

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

I have three csv files, out which I am going to make 6 traces in total (2 from each), I want to know if there is a way I can chain multiple csv uploads in plotly js code and how will I specifically call data from each.

From the website this is the template:

```
Plotly.d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts- apple.csv", function(err, rows){

function unpack(rows, key) {
   return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
}


var trace1 = {
   type: "scatter",
   mode: "lines",
   name: 'AAPL High',
   x: unpack(rows, 'Date'),
   y: unpack(rows, 'AAPL.High'),
   line: {color: '#17BECF'}
}

var trace2 = {
   type: "scatter",
   mode: "lines",
   name: 'AAPL Low',
   x: unpack(rows, 'Date'),
   y: unpack(rows, 'AAPL.Low'),
   line: {color: '#7F7F7F'}
}

 var data = [trace1,trace2];

 var layout = {
   title: 'Basic Time Series',
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
})
```

Any solution would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I did this today, I can suggest to visit the page https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/
The trick is to **create an empty plot and then use the command *addTraces* inside the csv call**. This work perfectly, I will update my example soon.